# How to position an included layout on the bottom of the original layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having problem laying out my included layout directly below the parent layout.
The original layout of the activity is a Relative Layout, I nested it under a Linear layout followd by the

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"/>
```

but they end up covering each other.
Below is the full layout .xml I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dip">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:elevation=".5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/h_biglogo"
            android:paddingTop="8.5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hiaTextField" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:hint="UserName"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:text="historya"
            android:autoText="false"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
            android:text="password"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:id="@+id/hiaButton"
            android:onClick="hiaSubmitClick"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"

            android:alpha="20"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fbButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login using Facebook"

            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaButton"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:alpha="20"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:onClick="hiaFbLogin" />


    </RelativeLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width and height of the parent LinearLayout as match_parent and match_parent respectively.

And for the relative layout change the height and width to wrap_content and match_parent respectively.

Other alternative you have is :
Remove the parent LinearLayout and for the layout you are including make the following changes :

```
 <include android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
          android:layout_below="@id/fbButton" 
          layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"/>
```

Comment: I tried removing the parent linearLayout and used 
<include
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"/> still over the other

Comment: add this property also android:layout_below="@id/fbButton"

Comment: I used this

<include
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_below="@id/fbButton"
        layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"/>

stil over the other.  Is it possible that the layout being included is the one responsible?

Comment: please set height as wrap_content.

Comment: Works now.  It is now directly below the parent layout not uner or above.  Thank you.  Can you please update your answer so others can reference the more complete and accurate code then I'll accept your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create this like below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dip">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation=".5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:paddingBottom="8.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8.5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:autoText="false"

            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:hint="UserName"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:text="historya"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="#AA000000"

            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:text="password"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiaButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaPassword"

            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:alpha="20"
            android:onClick="hiaSubmitClick"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"

            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fbButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha="20"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="hiaFbLogin"
            android:text="Login using Facebook"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_passport_search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For making the layout as you wish, you need to make your parent layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and make it's width & height to match_parent.

The complete layout is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dip">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include_passport_bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:elevation=".5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:paddingBottom="8.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8.5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/h_biglogo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:hint="UserName"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:text="historya"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaTextField"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:text="password"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiaButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaPassword"
            android:alpha="20"
            android:onClick="hiaSubmitClick"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fbButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hiaButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha="20"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_white"
            android:onClick="hiaFbLogin"
            android:text="Login using Facebook"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_passport_bottom"
        layout="@layout/activity_passport_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```